# What is a good Git's strategy for this case?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, branching-and-merging

I own two Git repositories:

- **ServerSide** repository (conceptual name)
- **ClientSide** repository.

**ServerSide** contains a `client` folder, empty initially, needing to be feed by the code from the latest commit of **ClientSide**'s master branch at deployment time.  (I only need to deploy **ServerSide**, since it is aiming to bring client with it)

What I would like is an automatic strategy to pull the content from **ClientSide**'s master branch into **ServerSide**.

Indeed, until now, each time I want to deploy `ServerSide`, I use the manual (and very bad) strategy consisting in totally clearing the `client` folder (`rm -rf *` => very risky), launching a process (bash for instance) that grabs content from my **ClientSide**'s (pure `cp` command) local master branch to the **ServerSide**'s `client` folder and commit/push the whole.

What would be a really efficient strategy to do the trick automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, **ClientSide** could be added to **ServerSide** as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

In **ServerSide**:
`git submodule add <ClientSide> client`

This creates a client directory linked with your ClientSide repository.

At deployment time:

```
cd client
git pull
# then commit the update of submodule client in ServerSide and deploy
```

Comment: Git warns about: "'client' already exists in the index" and `git rm -r client` did the trick :)  I'm testing the whole now

Comment: With this strategy, can I pull easily just one folder from the `client`? not the whole

Comment: No, this is not possible. But what you could do in this case is create a 3rd repository used as a submodule of both ClientSide and ServerSide.